# How do I make a WebDav call using HttpClient?

Tags: java, httpclient, webdav, jackrabbit, sling

Specifically I want to call `MKCOL` through [`HttpClient`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) to create a folder for Apache Jackrabbit through the Sling REST API.

I've tried variants of

```
BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest request = new BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest("MKCOL", restUrl);
```

But no dice so far.  I'm guessing this is less difficult than I'm making it.

I also see there is [`MkColMethod`](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.2/org/apache/jackrabbit/webdav/client/methods/MkColMethod.html) for something like

```
MkColMethod mkColMethod = new MkColMethod(restUrl);
```

But I don't know how to utilize this.  I think it may have worked with a previous version of HttpClient.  I'm using 4.x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best is to look at the Sling integration tests, which use Sling's RESTful APIs to create content.

The ["old" SlingIntegrationTestClient class](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/bundles/commons/testing/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/commons/testing/integration/SlingIntegrationTestClient.java) is used to test Sling itself and uses `httpclient 3.x` to create content. It is used by the tests found [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/launchpad/integration-tests), so you can find examples there.

The ["new" SlingClient class](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/testing/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/testing/tools/sling/SlingClient.java) is meant to be a cleaner and simpler re-implementation of that, used by the Sling testing tools described at http://sling.apache.org/site/sling-testing-tools.html . It uses `httpclient 4.x` which has a slightly different API.

The SlingClient.mkdir and mkdirs methods do use the MKCOL method.

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I couldn't get this to work.  There must be something wrong with my HttpClient/authentication configuration as my request attempts hang.  I'm going to try a different approach (not using Sling)

Answer (score 1):

[Sardine](https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine) is an easy to use webdav client for Java