# How to post form data to Apache Sling using a Java servlet

Tags: apache, servlets, osgi, jackrabbit, sling

I am trying to POST the data from a html page and post it to a sling using a java servlet..

**Note: My webapp is running in tomcat(port 8080), and my sling runs in a different port(8999).**

my html is a very simple form with just one input box

```
<form action = "/data" method="post">
<input type="text" name="input" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

and in the servlet i have received the data in the input box.

```
Sting name = request.getParameter("input")
```

I also went through to the documentation in the official docs, but didnt find anything helpful regarding this.

Any code that help me understand the post part will be helpful.

Comment: you are trying to store the form information into the jcr repository? you don't really need a servlet for that, just POST it to the path you wish.

Comment: you mean to say like this ?? <form action='http://host:port/node/subnode/' method=post/> ??? isint this way revealing the path of the repository ???.. or am i mistaking your idea ? @santiagozky

Comment: @santiagozky or is something like servlet mapping possible ??... like we specify a url pattern in the form action and write a web.xml for the same pattern to access the jcr rrepository  ??

Comment: yes, that would reveal the path, why is that a problem? just manage your permissions accordingly

Comment: you have 2 different apps, one in 8080 and one in 8999, you want to post from the html into a servlet in 8080 and then post it forward to sling, is this correct?

Comment: @santiagozky yes that is correct.. servlet in 8080 has to post data to sling in 8999

Comment: can't you use <form action="http:/myserver:8999/data" method="post> ?

Comment: Giving the url in the form works for me.. but instead of writing permissions of handling data, I am writing a servlet to store the data from html to sling. just like an extra layer that will interact between html and sling. and moreover the webapp can be accessed from any system, so system level permissions is not a great option(IMO).

Answer (score 0):

Reworked answer taking into account your question edits: it looks like what you want is to make POST requests from another Java application to Sling.

If that's correct you can use the httpclient library which is discussed in another question here, see [How do I make a WebDav call using HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023876/how-do-i-make-a-webdav-call-using-httpclient/6028984#6028984)

Comment: I dont think my previous way of questioning was not clear, i have updated the question in it.. Please see if you could help